# How do you feel about a PMSE contest?

Tags: discussion, contests

Occasionally, StackExchange communities hold contests centered around some particular set of activities on the site. These events can be a fun way to get more people engaged in making the site a better place.

I wanted to get some ideas from the community. If there is enough interest, then someone could post a Meta question to get the planning started.

My thought is the contest could be focused on editing, but we're open to suggestions.

We would need ideas on how to judge the edits although editing is something that is easy to quantify; the [Users -> Editors](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) tab gives a breakdown of total edits all time, by year, quarter, month, and week.

[image: Users Editors Tab User Edits View]

This makes it easy to compare your stats with the community as a whole.

Other ideas that could have potential is anything that could help create broader interest in the site and bring in more project managers.

So, does a contest interest you, and would you be interested in helping to plan it?

Answer (score 1):

the editing contest sounds good, although I have to confess that, even with all my freaking mania of organization, there aren't much posts to be edited in PMSE (is our community too good to leave edit breaches? Hehe).

One possibility that I believe could give some boost to our community would be to pick the '**top question of the week**', not necessarily being a question *raised during* the week, for the sake of clarity, but a question that the community agrees to be an interesting and valuable question beyond PMSE.

Then, with the question in mind (and the link in the transfer area), we could define some targets (as any project, we need to define goals!) like reach 1k views for that specific question within 1 week, reach 5 different answers or something like this.

The prize? Gather more involvement in our community from outsiders. If only 1 out of 100 visitors bind to the community, we reached our goal!

Any thoughts?

Comment: How do we determine the question of the week? What's the criteria? Maybe change it up week by week? Highest voted, then most viewed? Highest voted question for a new user?

Comment: All criteria you mention are nice... I was wondering something like a pooling with some questions that one consider interesting but has a low view rate, for instance.